# php multidimensional array foreach

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am using three different arrays of the same length, they are filled with values during a foreach loop:

```
foreach(......)
   {
   $array1[]=value1;
   $array2[]=value2;
   $array3[]=value3;
   }
```

Then these arrays must be echoed:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < count($array1))
   {
   echo $array1[i];
   echo $array2[i];
   echo $array3[i];
   $i++;
   }
```

Is there a more elegant way to this this, for example a foreach loop an a multidimensional array?

Comment: You can use a `foreach` on any of your arrays and get the key as well: `foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)` and then you already have your first value and the key for the values in the other arrays. But I would probably use only one array to store all the data.

Comment: try `array_map` or  `array_walk` or `array_walk_recursive` these functions will help you achieve this.

Comment: can you complete foreach(.....) ? what hides the dots ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your arrays :

```
$a1 = [2,3,4];
$a2 = [6,7,8];
$a3 = [9,10,11];


array_walk($a1, function($v, $k) use($a2, $a3)
{
    echo $v;
    echo $a2[$k];
    echo $a3[$k];
});
```

Or simply

```
foreach($a1 as $k => $v)
{
    echo $v;
    echo $a2[$k];
    echo $a3[$k];
}
```

Note:

You should never placing a count in while condition,
because it will called for each iterations ! that is not optimized

```
while($i < count($array1))
```

should be replaced by

```
$count = count($array1);
while($i < $count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make an object of it? Probably create an actual class but StdClass works.

```
foreach(...)
{
    $obj = new StdClass();
    $obj->value1 = $value1;
    $obj->value2 = $value2;
    $obj->value3 = $value3;
    $array[] = $obj;
}

foreach($array as $obj)
{
    echo $obj->value1;
    echo $obj->value2;
    echo $obj->value3;
}
```

Still not very elegant but no ugly while loop.

Comment: You can pull that object out from `foreach` and use of its instance into `foreach`.